# The filter feature in our Kendo Grid only returns records from the first page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We used Kendo UI to build the data grid for our ASP.NET MVC application.

When I try to filter data with Kendo UI, the filter option only permits us to filter records on the 1st page:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poF5Y.png)

For example, if I want to filter for grade `AO25` on page 3 and am currently on page 1, nothing comes up:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJM0I.png)

Even if I navigate to page 3 and try to filter, it only brings up the records from the 1st page:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRwJy.png)

Even trying to filter for a particular record on the same page (in this case, grade `AO25`) brings up nothing:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lw1G.png)

The same issues applies to the other columns in our grid.

This is the object we send to the `kendoGrid()` method (some extraneous details were truncated):

```js
dataSource: {
    ...
    pageSize: @(defaultGridPageSize),
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: false
},
filterable: true, 
sortable: {
    mode: "multiple",
    allowUnsort: true,
    showIndexes: false
},
pageable: {
    refresh: true,
    pageSizes: [@(gridPageSizes)],
    @Html.Partial("_GridPagerMessages")
},
scrollable: false,
dataBound: onDataBound,
columns: [
    ...
    {
        field: "Grade",
        title: "Grade",
        filterable: { multi: true, search: true },
        width: 100
    },
    ...
],
```

I wasn't the one that initially wrote the grid views (the person who did is no longer with us).
I've spent a while searching for a solution (to no avail) browsing the documentation on Telerik's website, and trying out different configurations of the properties of the `dataSource` object and I wasn't able to get the filter functionality to behave as desired.

Changing the `serverFiltering` property to true in my `.cshtml` view page didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Try adding `serverFiltering: true` to the dataSource. You can read more on serverFiltering [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/serverfiltering).

Comment: @Supersnake: it was one of the things I previously tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok I would suggest editing this [kendo ui dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AqoSeQag) with the properties you're using for your grid. This is the example I've been playing with and setting the `serverFiltering` property to true has been correcting the issue.